# How do you avoid Belial's slam attacks?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm used to playing a Monk, where I'm defensive enough that the slams don't really bother me and have enough healing that I never really gave them any thought.

Now, I'm playing a Demon Hunter, and even though he telegraphs the slams with a big green meteor circle, I don't know how to avoid the impact. Even if his arm doesn't hit me, I'm still taking damage from the slams. Since I die in 2 hits to the slams, and my healing options are limited (potions have a cooldown and my damage output isn't exactly amazing while I'm running for my life to take advantage of Shadow Power), the best option is probably to avoid taking damage from them altogether.

**Is there any pattern to his slams? How should I *move* to avoid them once he starts telegraphing that that's his plan?**

To clarify, since there has been some confustion, this *is not* asking for Demon Hunter specific strategies. This *is* asking about Belial's attack pattern and how to predict and avoid it in general.

Comment: Go back to playing Monk!

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Monk is still my main, but farming Inferno alone is boring.

Comment: Are you currently in normal?  If so, lots and lots of amethyst.  Also, Vault.

Comment: @MBraedley I don't want demon-hunter-specific strategies. I want to know the pattern of slams and where to stand to avoid them. But no, I'm in Nightmare right now with this character.

Comment: @StrixVaria: In that case, never-mind.  I have a feeling it's semi-random though,

Comment: @StrixVaria the solution is quite as simple as just avoiding everything. Everything in the fight is 100% avoidable if you react fast enough, although take into consideration latency. His slams are targetted at you if you're the only player (soloing) and will center on your position at the point he decided to slam. You have about 1 second to get completely clear, baring in mind that the graphic is smaller than the action and that you need to move outwards rather than inwards - being under his arm (but outside of the green) is still a direct hit.

Comment: You are invincible when using smoke screen, and you can keep shooting while it's active - there is no need to run.  It also has enormously short cooldown.  With the extra-time rune and some extra blue-mana regen, you can pretty much kill belial with a demon hunter without being hit, and barely moving.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He has 2 different punch attacks (this doesn't include his fire/poison breath move, or his meteor phase).

The first is just a generic one handed punch/slam that is aimed very close to your character. To dodge this move you just have to move as soon as you see him winding up. Any movement abilities can help here (Vault, Spiritwalk, Leap etc) because this is his quickest and hardest to dodge move (but it's also the weakest).

The second is a 3 punch combo, this move can either be a right/left/both combo or a right/right/both combo (both seem to strike the same places so the strategy is the same). Both combos will not move once they're started, that is, once he starts the first punch, he'll keep punching the same area even if you move away.

To dodge this combo, move to the right when you see a green circle to your left, and then immediately after it hits, start moving to your left (movement abilities will help again here), keep moving until you've moved past where the green circle was. His next two hits (either left hand or right hand, then both) should miss, and you're able to fire away without fear of him striking again until the animation is done.

Answer (score 3):

[I took my level 60 monk into normal and did some testing.](http://twitch.tv/monoxide0184/b/321516899) The only generic solution seems to be 'dodge faster'. Which arm he uses to smash down is somewhat random, but his aiming isn't. He will specifically target somewhere very near you, and the area that the blast hits is wide enough that it will always hit if you don't move. Even at the very edge of the arena, he still seems to target you spot on.

If you are in melee range, then he seems to use a stabbing style attack which may be easier to dodge. I have a feeling that the following is true though:

- His melee range attack:

  - Always centred on your current position.
  - Explodes for a certain radius around that.
  - Likely hits harder, but I didn't think to turn on damage numbers to verify this.
- His ranged slam attack:

  - Conal attack.
  - Harder to dodge at range due to needing to move further. Can't get too close or you trigger his melee range attack though.

From this, your best bet is to stay around mid-range. Use movement increasing abilities like Vault and abilities like Sentry that will give you DPS, even if you have to just keep running the whole time.

Answer (score 1):

You should be running before he telegraphs the slam. If you wait until the indicator appears to begin moving, it is usually too late.

Consider watching some videos of DH soloing belial on inferno. There are plenty on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

Demon hunter specific:
Take Smoke Screen and Preparation.
Everytime he marks the ground under you, just pop Smoke Screen - you won't take any damage.
Advantage of this approach is that you can stay in one place and just spam your primary damage ability.
When he starts casting explosion, if you are caught within them, again, time your Smoke Screen and you won't take any damage.

About his pattern - it's random. I remeber one fight (with DH) where he didn't aim me once.
I guess +movement speed gear could help you on him.

Comment: He was asking specifically for non-DH specific strategies.

Comment: @fbueckert: What are you talking about?  *"Now, I'm playing a Demon Hunter, and [..] I don't know how to avoid the impact."*

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft "I don't want demon-hunter-specific strategies. I want to know the pattern of slams and where to stand to avoid them."  Comment on the question.

Comment: @fbuckert: Ermm,that's why I divided my answer into two paragraph. First one DH specific and second one general tips. Question is - is there any pattern. Answer is - no, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on avoiding them in the end, and just made sure I had enough life related equipment/skills to survive being hit. He doesn't hit very often, and I was able to use potions/skills/health globes often enough to kill him on my first attempt at this strategy.

Use the templar too, since he will heal you.

Answer (score 0):

Using a level 48 monk, I noticed that Belial's hitting strategy is predictable (at least on PS3).  By starting at the extreme left side his first and sometimes second smashes missed completely - or at least enough to survive them.  The third one would kill me instantly.  However, if I engaged the Monk's Tempest Rush ability, as soon as he wound up to do his first smash, I could run along the inside edge to the opposite side.  This allowed me to attack him while I was running, but also, once I was at the other side, Belial was still stuck in his trio of attacks.  This let me get a few (about 4-6) seconds of free attacks in before he turned around.  Then I would head back to the other side.